# how to stop the slider as I hover over it?

Tags: d3.js

he javascript code I tried :

```js
$( ".rotate-slider" ).hover(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".rotate-slider" ).stop( true, true ).fadeOut();
}, function() {
  $( this ).find( ".rotate-slider" ).stop( true, true ).fadeIn();
});
```

also I tried to use css to get it :

```css
.rotating-slide:hover .slider
{
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Unfortunately,none of the above code seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use something like this :

```html
$( ".rotate-slider li" ).hover(function() {      
    clearInterval(rotateInterval);
}, function() {
  rotateInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
                if(!rotateSlider.slidesContainer.hasClass('animate')){
                    rotateSlider.slidesContainer.addClass('animate')
                }
                currentRotation = currentRotation - rotateSlider.slideAngle;
                rotateSlider.slidesContainer.css('transform', 'translateX(-50%) rotate('+currentRotation+'deg)');
            }, 4000);
});
```